# $_GET variable passed in CURL POST

Tags: php, curl

I can't figure out why the code below doesn't work, but it does when I replace `'page' => $page_no` with `'page' => 4`.

The code:

```
$page_no = $_GET['page_no'];

$base_url = 'url here';
$api_id = 'api here';
$secret = ' secret here ';

$postvars = [
    'query' => 'query here',
    'page' => $page_no,
    'fields' => ['ip', 'city','province', 'country_code', 'country'],
    'fattened' => true
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$base_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postvars));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$api_id:$secret");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

$json = curl_exec($ch);
```

The URL I am using is: https://example.com/search.php?page_no=4

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try a simple `var_dump($postvars);` to see what is actually getting put in that array

Comment: This code looks fine. It must be somewhere else. Your url is exactly `.../search.php?page_no=4` ?

Comment: One of the reasons you're asked to create a [mcve] is that it helps you identify the problem before you need to ask a question here. In your case, your problem has nothing to do with curl. It's that (you think) you're not getting a value passed from the query string. So a [mcve] in your case would be a page with nothing but `var_dump($_GET)`. How does it look if you do that?

Comment: @RiggsFolly That was the issue - is was a `string` instead of an `int`. Thanks!

Comment: @miken32 You are very correct. I will make sure to use that page before posting. I didn't know where the problem was and should have `var_dump`ed it. Thanks!